# register_shutdown_function() and die()

Tags: php, smarty, die

Can I somehow check, if my script was canceled by `die()` in [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)?

Something like this:

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

die('Calling die()');

function shutdown()
{
    if (???)
    {
        // Script was canceled by die()
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: On my website, I use Smarty. So maybe check, if `$smarty->display()` was called or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kind of... but you won't necessarily like how it has to be done.

Since there is no hook that allows you to check if `die` was called, you will have to somehow fake it. Assuming that you cannot touch all calls to `die`, that leaves only one option: set some state that signifies "`die` was called" by default, and remove that state only at the very end of your script, when you know that you are going to exit without `die` having been called earlier.

"Set some state" sounds suspiciously like global variables and that should be a last resort, so let's use a constant for state:

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
if (condition) die('Calling die()');

// since we reached this point, die was not called
define('DIE_NOT_CALLED', true);

function shutdown()
{
    if (!defined('DIE_NOT_CALLED'))
    {
        // Script was canceled by die()
    }
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/U9qZK)**.

Comment: yes this would work, but I think I would prefer to define a DIE_CALLED, just before calling die, rather than defining a DIE_NOT_CALLED after... what if there is another die later in the script?

Comment: @Andrew the point is that in the very common case where you have a single exit point (e.g. a front controller) you only need to do this once, at the end of it. Whereas defining `DIE_CALLED` would require you to touch (and keep in sync!) all calls to `die`. That may not be possible (e.g. code you don't own calls it), and if it is then your problem can be solved very simply by swapping calls to `die` with some `custom_die` that does whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way would be to set a globally accessible variable at the end of your script. You can then check in the shutdown function if this variable has been set. If not, the script was terminated prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should avoid `die` and `exit` if you're deploying on FastCGId. It kills processes and thus prevents them from being re-used for another run.

If you simply want to check if Smarty has output something or not, you might want to try something like:

```
MySmarty extends Smarty {
  public static $_has_displayed = false;
  public function display(/* params */) {
    $t = parent::display(/* params */);
    self::$_has_displayed = true;
    return $t;
  }
}

register_shutdown_function('foo');
function foo() {
  if (!MySmarty::$_has_displayed) {
    echo "OMG I failed!";
  }
}
```